# Slingshot Latency Compensation creates Blobs that make the appsize grow steadily. revokeObjectURL doesn't seem to work on them

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, meteor-slingshot, revokeobjecturl

EDIT:

So I found out where the real problem is. It seems like the real problem is the creation of blobs through the [latency compensation oft Slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot#show-uploaded-file-before-it-is-uploaded-latency-compensation). Because when I outcomment the latency compensation the filesize doesn't grow

```
this.uploader.url(true);
```

..creates a Blob URL. I tried all kinds of "revoceObjectURL" on that url after they are used:

```
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
    webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
```

I'm calling each method 2 times to see if it was successful because [I suspect a network error](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob)
I neither get the network error, nor does the Filesize shrink to it's initial value.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the device, maybe it is gone.

Comment: Restarting the device is no real option as the app needs to handle lots of data and it grows to 500mb until it does what it has to do (it uploades images over wifi to a server) - but I found out who the real bad guy is, see edit